# Amazon Linux AMI Beta - node.js not compiled with opensll crypto support

Tags: amazon-ec2

I've installed nodejs, npm, and required modules to run my chat application. When run, I got these error. What can I do ?

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-170-91-52 ~]$ cd chat
[ec2-user@ip-10-170-91-52 chat]$ node server.js

node.js:181
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
Error: node.js not compiled with openssl crypto support.
    at tls.js:45:9
    at NativeModule.compile (node.js:430:5)
    at node.js:398:18
    at https.js:22:11
    at NativeModule.compile (node.js:430:5)
    at Function.require (node.js:398:18)
    at Function._load (module.js:285:25)
    at require (module.js:364:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/connect/1.4.0/package/lib/https.js:14:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:420:26)
[ec2-user@ip-10-170-91-52 chat]$ ^C
[ec2-user@ip-10-170-91-52 chat]$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install OpenSSL:
`sudo yum install openssl openssl-devel`

Comment: I do that, then run the code I got the following error:

Comment: node.js:181
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
Error: node.js not compiled with openssl crypto support.
    at tls.js:45:9
    at NativeModule.compile (node.js:430:5)
    at node.js:398:18
    at https.js:22:11
    at NativeModule.compile (node.js:430:5)
    at Function.require (node.js:398:18)
    at Function._load (module.js:285:25)
    at require (module.js:364:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/connect/1.4.0/package/lib/https.js:14:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:420:26)

Comment: Have you recompile nodejs after that?

Comment: things rediculously turn out right, I have no idea how I got to where I'm, but for sure, if I have to install all this sh.t again, I won't make it.

Comment: No dice!  I have the same problems with a brand new ec2 instance and I originally configured, maked, installed without openssl, then did what you suggested and still have the same error after another config, make and install.  My js that Im trying to get to run is a simple 1 liner console.log("Hello World");, same error.  I used this site for the instructions...a little dated regarding the amazon interface shots http://www.embracingthecloud.com/2010/12/05/InstallingNodejsOnAmazonEC2.aspx